# Is an ellipse determined by three points and tangent lines at two of them?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I have three points, $A$, $B$, and $C$, on an ellipse; two tangent lines at $A$ and $B$ are also known. Are these enough to determine the whole ellipse?

Comment: It is well-known that you need five points to uniquely determine a conic section. Replacing two of the points with two slopes sounds like it ought to be fine. So from a pure degrees of freedom perspective, the answer is "probably".

Comment: Points of tangency count twice, so you effectively have five points, determining a unique conic. (If the tangent lines at $A$ and $B$ have direction vectors $u$ and $v$, then you can define fourth and fifth points $A':=A+\alpha u$ and $B':=B+\beta v$, find the unique conic containing these, then let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ tend to $0$.)

Comment: Related (duplicate?): ["What is the equation for an ellipse given 3 points and the tangent line at those points?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2621665/409). That question asks about specific points and tangents, but the general principle holds. [My answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2621751/409) walks-through the process of determining the equation of the conic from the three given points and just two of the tangents.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, the tangent lines at A,B and C are all known and they form a three-sided open figure that is tangent at A,B and C with the ellipse. I want a proof for the conclusion that the condition can determine uniquely an ellipse.

Comment: @fosuwxb: [Five points determine a unique conic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_points_determine_a_conic), and as I mentioned (and effectively demonstrate in [my linked answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2621751/409)) points of tangency count twice, so your given information definitely determines a unique *conic*. Whether the conic is specifically an *ellipse* depends upon how the given points and tangents are arranged. Unless/until you provide details about the arrangement, the specific nature of the conic cannot be predicted.

Comment: To get an ellipse, point $C$ must lie inside the parabola touching the given lines at $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thanks. I get a paper as follows:

Paris Pamfilos . A Gallery of Conics by Five Elements,Forum Geometricorum, Volume 14 (2014) 295–348.
My problem was completely solved.

Comment: Go ahead and post your solution as an Answer. It is totally ok for an Asker to post an answer to their own question.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments by OP:

> [See] [Paris Pamfilos, *A Gallery of Conics by Five Elements*, Forum
> Geometricorum, Volume 14 (2014) 295–348](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2014volume14/FG201431.pdf). My problem was completely
> solved

Answer (score 0):

A conic by five distinct points can be constructed as follows: consider the lines $d_{12}=0,d_{34}=0,d_{13}=0$ and $d_{24}=0$ and form the pencil of conics

$$(1-\lambda)d_{12}d_{34}+\lambda d_{13}d_{24}=0.$$ these are all the conics through $1,2,3,4$. Then plug the coordinates of $5$ in the equation and determine $\lambda$ to get the conic by $1,2,3,4,5$.

Now if $1$ and $2$ get closer and closer, $d_{12}$ tends to a tangent, let $t_1$, and the pencil becomes

$$(1-\lambda)t_{1}d_{34}+\lambda d_{13}d_{14}=0.$$

If $4$ also migrates to $3$, defining the tangent $t_3$,

$$(1-\lambda)t_{1}t_3+\lambda d_{13}^2=0.$$